# IServiceProvider (ctor) is not equal as IServiceProvider (scope)?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

im trying to resolve an object from a class resolved on scope, it appears that the IServiceProvider from ctor is from root scope so Im getting a different instance than the object being resolved on this current scope

See below code for more details

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace TestProjectDI;

public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddSingleton<BarHandlerResolver>();

        services.AddTransient<BarHandler>();

        services.AddScoped<ScopeFoo>();


        using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var sp = scope.ServiceProvider;

            var tt = sp.GetType();

            var scopeFoo = sp.GetService<ScopeFoo>();

            scopeFoo.UID = Guid.NewGuid();



            var handlerResolver = sp.GetRequiredService<BarHandlerResolver>();

            Assert.Equal(scopeFoo.UID, handlerResolver.GetHandlerInstanceFromSP_Ctor().ScopeFoo.UID); // this doesnt work as sp is resolved from ctor? should the sp in ctor be the same as the one resolved from this scope?
            Assert.Equal(scopeFoo.UID, handlerResolver.GetHandlerInstanceFromSP_Param(sp).ScopeFoo.UID); // this works as sp is from scope?
        }
    }
}

public class BarHandlerResolver
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public BarHandlerResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public BarHandler GetHandlerInstanceFromSP_Ctor()
    {
        return serviceProvider.GetService<BarHandler>();
    }

    public BarHandler GetHandlerInstanceFromSP_Param(IServiceProvider serviceProviderFromParent)
    {
        return serviceProviderFromParent.GetService<BarHandler>();
    }
}

public class BarHandler
{
    public BarHandler(ScopeFoo scopeFoo)
    {
        ScopeFoo = scopeFoo;
    }

    public ScopeFoo ScopeFoo { get; }
}

public class ScopeFoo
{
    public Guid UID { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe I need to inject something in BarHandlerResolver instead of IServiceProvider?

```
// this doesnt work as sp is resolved from ctor? should the sp in ctor be the same as the one resolved from this scope?
Assert.Equal(scopeFoo.UID, handlerResolver.GetHandlerInstanceFromSP_Ctor().ScopeFoo.UID); 

// this works as sp is from scope?
Assert.Equal(scopeFoo.UID, handlerResolver.GetHandlerInstanceFromSP_Param(sp).ScopeFoo.UID);
```

Comment: `BarHandler` is added as **transient** in your `services.AddTransient<BarHandler>()` line, so every call to `GetRequiredService<BarHandler>()` will return a new instance.

Comment: should it resolve ScopeFoo as scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C# code to register services is invalid - but .NET will let you run it anyway. If you change your `BuildServiceProvider()` call to specify `( validateScopes: true )` then you'll get a runtime exception when you call `GetHandlerInstanceFromSP_Ctor()`:

> `InvalidOperationException`
> Cannot resolve 'BarHandler' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'ScopeFoo'.

You should read this page fully: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines

---

> it appears that the `IServiceProvider` from ctor (in `BarHandlerResolver`) is from root scope

Correct: because your `BarHandlerResolver` is registered with `AddSingleton` it means `handlerResolver`'s `IServiceProvider` (passed into its ctor) will be the same as the root `IServiceProvider` - so the `BarHandlerResolver.GetHandlerInstanceFromSP_Ctor()` method will always use the root SP to resolve `BarHandler`.

...and because `BarHandler` is added with `AddTransient` and `ScopeFoo` is added with `AddScoped` but `ScopeFoo` is resolved using the Root SP, which *should not be possible* (and that's why the `InvalidOperationException` above gets thrown when you use `validateScopes: true`).

...but .NET's DI container *does* let you resolve scoped-services from the root scope when `validateScopes: false`.

- (I assume it does this to reduce *developer-friction* when users need something to "just work for now..." with the expectation that the C# programmer will fix things properly later on (especially considering that `validateScopes: true` is implied when `Environment.IsProduction() == true`).)
- So when `validateScopes: false`, the root SP will use a hidden "root scope" for all scoped services created for services in the root scope.

  - [This is documented on the DI Guidelines page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#scoped-service-as-singleton). So basically, it promotes all root-scoped services to singletons, which may be highly undesirable, especially for `IDisposable` services.
  - So if you call `GetHandlerInstanceFromSP_Ctor()` twice, then the second `BarHandler` is created using the same `ScopeFoo` instance as the first `BarHandler`.
- But you should not depend on this behaviour, because it means you can't easily dispose of the implicit root scope.